# explanation for activate_plugin function in wordpress core

Tags: wordpress, hook

This function is in plugin.php file in wordpress core.
I read the code and didn't get quietly what does it do.
Can anyone give some explanation for this function?

Answer (score 1):

All plugins are stored in an array in the `active_plugins option`. The array contains the file path to each plugin that is active.

When we want to activate a plugin we need to determine what its path will be, then we pass that path into `activate_plugin($plugin_path)`.

We need to include the `plugin.php` file from `wp-admin/includes/` folder before using `activate_plugin()`.

**For Example**

```
// Define the new plugin you want to activate
$plugin_path = '/path/to/your/new/plugin.php';
// Get already-active plugins   
$active_plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
// Make sure your plugin isn't active
if (isset($active_plugins[$plugin_path]))
    return;

// Include the plugin.php file so you have access to the activate_plugin() function
require_once(ABSPATH .'/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
// Activate your plugin
activate_plugin($plugin_path);
```

[Reference link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/how-to-activate-plugins-via-code)

[Read the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/activate_plugin)